# Select multiple pages class one line

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to apply certain rules to specific pages on WordPress. I'm trying to target the page class/ID and applying the rules in one line instead of multiple separate pages rules. I'm separating the classes by comma, but it seems to not work, what am doing wrong/is it possible ?

```
.page-id-62, .page-id-63, .page-id-64 .absolute-footer.dark {
   color: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.52);
}
```

Just for knowledge when you select multiple selectors is the space required ?

Cheers to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean multiple selector `.absolute-footer.dark` element in page/post ID 62, 63, 64,... Here is working code:

```
.page-id-62 .absolute-footer.dark, .page-id-63 .absolute-footer.dark, .page-id-64 .absolute-footer.dark {
   color: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.52)!important; /* !important just in case */
}
```

Comment: You are a magician my friend, thank you so much, learnt a lot cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible. you need to add .absolute-footer.dark after each page id class

```
.page-id-62 .absolute-footer.dark, 
.page-id-63 .absolute-footer.dark, 
.page-id-64 .absolute-footer.dark 
  {
    color: rgba(66, 66, 66, 0.52); 
   }
```

Comment: Thanks mate appreciate the help great job learnt today a lot :)